# bootstrap trigger modal from javascript function give Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know it is a "famous" issue but I am still fighting with it.
**Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function**
I call my scripts in head (also tried at the bottom just before the end of html, but I have onload functions!):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
```

In my function.js file:

> $('#ModalEmailAlert').modal();

And I tried also

> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  $('#ModalEmailAlert').modal();
>   });

```
function OpenModal(ModalName){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#'+ModalName).modal();
    });
}
```

I also tried to call jquery from cdn (google and jquery) but at the moment call it from my website to make sure it comes first and complete.

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Well, one problem is you have a malformed `script` element after your `bootstrap.min.js` one: `<script type="text/javascript"</script>` Other than that, we can't help you without a lot more information. See: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I missed up by copy/paste from the source. Now it is correct (like in my page)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this out, if your applciation structure is as below

- index.html

  - js

    - jquery-1.12.4.min.js
    - bootstrap.min.js
    - functions.js

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>`

Hope this will help you.

You can't have the below code like this

```
function OpenModal(ModalName){
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#'+ModalName).modal();
  });
}
```

Change it to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function OpenModal(ModalName){
    $('#'+ModalName).modal();
  }

  OpenModal('modal1');
});
```

**Or else**

Add an `onclick` event in `HTML`
Eg: `<button type="submit" onclick="OpenModal('modal1')">Open Modal</button>`

Comment: Thanks @Shiladitya. I did update my post. My description was not correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I call this function?
Before I was calling OpenModal(CallLogin); and now I have:
Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenModal is not defined

Comment: I mean before I was calling OpenModal(CallLogin); from:

function CallLogin(ActionPending,ActionPendingContent){
.......
if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
 document.getElementById("CallLogin").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
 OpenModal(CallLogin);
}
So, now, how to call from there?
Sorry for being a pain in the neck!

Comment: You entire code will go inside  `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});` and change the code `OpenModal("CallLogin")`, you are missing **double quotes**

Comment: Thank you @Shiladitya for your help.